# What is a destructor with the friend specifier?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor

I was browsing the [cppreference page about destructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor), and noticed two places which seem to indicate the existence of a friend destructor.

> *decl-specifier-seq* - **friend**, inline, virtual, or nothing (no return type)
>
> ...
>
> At a namespace scope or in a **friend** declaration within a different class...

The concept of a friend destructor makes absolutely no sense to me, and I have never seen this in practice.  I was hoping somebody could clear this up and explain why a destructor would ever have the friend specifier, and what that would even look like.

Comment: `decl-specifier-seq  -  friend, inline, virtual, or nothing (no return type) ` seems broken to me - friend et al are not return types.

Comment: I never seen and never tried about it but you can make a destructor private, so in this case you can want to call the private destructor by it's friend class manually by calling like that "object_ptr->~object_class();" instead of delete keyword to control the object destruction.

Comment: @rca that'd be the case with a regular friend class

Comment: It's in the standard draft too, ([here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/special#class.dtor-1)). Interesting question.

Comment: @kmdreko hmm you're right. What if we just want to define destructor of class A as a friend function in class B to allow this destructor to access private members of B? In short maybe we want to do something else via members of the class B during destruction of the class A. I believe nobody never use it but functionality is functionality, that's why somebody hate C++. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at the description for *id-expression* below *decl-specifier-seq*.  You can declare a destructor for another class as a friend.

```
class AClass;

class classB {
public:
    AClass *a;
    ~classB();
};

class AClass {
    friend classB::~classB();
    ~AClass();
};

classB::~classB() {
     delete a;
}
```

In this contrived example, without the `friend` declaration, `classB` would not be able to destroy the contained `AClass` object.

All of the usual benefits of friendship - like being able to access private and protected members of the class - would also apply, so this would allow the destructor for `classB` to access any private or protected member of `AClass`.

Comment: What you've given an example of is a friend declaration, not a destructor declaration.

Comment: @einpoklum "A friend declaration" is mentioned in both the language spec II have and the cppreference link under "destructors", and I think that's the context where using "friend" in the decl-specifier-seq is needed.

Comment: So if your destructor is private, but another class needs to destroy the object, you can allow that by specifying the other class's destructor as friend'?

Comment: @Ian I've never needed to do that, but that appears to be the intent.  (It could also be `protected`, and is not limited to member variables - you could `delete` a pointer with it.)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm it does not compile if the member was private or protected, only public members.

Comment: @oblivion I've replaced the contrived example with another one that compiles.

Comment: just wanted to add that the friend dtor must be public

Comment: destruction is just one use case. Think about static member functions and data as Priviliage Services.

Answer (score 0):

According to the standard ([class.dtor]/1), you are allowed to use the keyword `friend` when declaring a destructor:

> Each *decl-specifier* of the *decl-specifier-seq* of a destructor declaration (if any) shall be `friend`, `inline`, or `virtual`.

(Note: in C++20, you will also be able to declare destructors `constexpr`.)

However, you can't just take an ordinary destructor declaration in its class and add `friend`, *e.g.,*

```
struct S {
    friend ~S();
};
```

This doesn't work because (I believe, but can't find the standard quote to back it up right now) when you declare a function a friend, the compiler will look up the name in the containing namespace and, if it doesn't find it there, will make the function a member of that namespace.

However, something like this is perfectly valid:

```
struct S { ~S(); };
struct T {
    // ...
    friend S::~S();  // this is also a declaration of S's destructor
};
```

This allows `S`'s destructor to access private members of `T`, as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

To add the answers already given from design perspective:

Any time you want some other class to be `responsible` for the life cycle of your class' objects (`A`), or to prevent the destruction of an object, the `dtor` must be private.

A private `dtor` would prevent anybody else from deleting it except for the `responsible` class. The `deleter` method or `dtor` of responsible class now has to be friend of class `A` to have access to that private `dtor`.

use cases are reference counting or managing connection to a data base. so the `responsible` class will take a request to `delete`/`disconnect` your object and will decide accordingly.

This is why a `friend dtor` is handy.